# ls -al Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

I'm new in the use of the terminal. I have seen in a video that uses ls -al and I don't know what it is. I have found that ls -a is to list all the files even the hidden but I cannot find what does ls -al means. In the same terminal I write man ls -al and it says man: "invalid option -- l" So:

- What does ls -al mean ?
- Where can I this kind of information. Is there any kind of manual or tutorial for very beginners like me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ls` lists all the files in a folder

`ls -a` lists all the files, including hidden files

`ls -l` lists all the files, in "long format" which basically tells you anything you needed to know about the files

`ls -al` is a combination of `ls -a` and `ls -l`

You can find more information about a command by typing `man <command>`, ex: `man ls` will give you more information about `ls`. To exit man hit `q`.

Comment: If I type: "man ls -al" I get: "man: invalid option -- l" Anyway, now thanks to you I already know what does it mean. Thank you!

Comment: @Narcís oh, you can't use the arguments with `man`, you have to just use the `man command` and skim through the article to see what the arguments mean.

Comment: And if this solved your question you might want to mark it as accepted, by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer that helped you most.

Comment: Both answers Lipongo and Kevin are clear and very good. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

The command ls is for listing directory contents or file information.  The option -a if for listing all files.  The option -l means long listing, more detailed information.  When you combine them in ls -al you should get the long listing of all files, including hidden files.

If you google "Unix beginner tutorial guide" you should come up with a lot of usable sites to learn from.

From the error you are getting, the - you are placing is not the right kind.  This is possibly from copying and pasting the command from elsewhere.

Comment: If I type: "man ls -al" I get: "man: invalid option -- l" Anyway, now thanks to you I already know what does it mean. Thank you!

Comment: type `man ls` not `man ls -la`.

Answer (score 1):

- **`-a`** means include all files, including the current directory, parent directory and files whose names begin with a dot.
- **`-l`** means display in long format.

To find out how the arguments affect the output of a command, use **`man command`** to see the documentation for the **`command`**. For example, **`man ls`**.